# How to replace/delete lines starts with particular word in Eclipse?

Tags: regex, eclipse

Some cases, I have to replace/delete lines starts with particular word like 'public'  'private' Java classes or `<version>` for XML file.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${version.bean.validation.hibernate}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Here using find/replace, I want to delete all lines starts with `'<version>'`. 
How to achieve this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use this regexp: `^\s+<version>.*$`
This will remove all lines starting with `<version>`. Make sure you have checked the checkbox "Regular expression"

Answer (score 9):

See the image:

1. add regular expression as  Jens correctly mentioned   `^\s+<version>.*$`
2. put nothing in here.
3. Check on regular expression option.
4. Click **Replace All**.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use the following regular expression to hide lines starting with 'public' -

**Regex Line Replacement**

- `public(.*)\R`

**Eclipse Config**

[image]

**Example**

[image]