# Eclipse - How to replace/delete lines

Tags: regex, eclipse

I am using eclipse v4.4.2
Text file contents have these lines:-

```
tosh1
tosh2
tosh3
tosh4
tosh4
tosh5
```

I am trying to match tosh4 and remove the lines.
The regex ^\s+tosh4.*$ is returning with "String Not found"

[Eclipse Search/Replace dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfuMt.jpg)
I am not seeing what is wrong with the regex. 
Please help. Thx.

Comment: Just match tosh4, or replace \s+ by .*

Comment: Avoid uploading images; and if you really have to: post them here; not as link to an external site!

Answer (score 3):

Lets dissect your regex:

```
^    fine: start of line
\s+  wrong: 1 or more SPACES
tosh4
```

tosh1 tosh2 tosh3 are for sure not spaces. That is why already the beginning of your regex can match!

what should work better

```
^.*tosh4.*$
```

Matching any line that contains tosh4. But as you are looking for a regular expression that get matching lines **deleted**, we have to enhance that to:

```
^.*tosh4.*\R
```

`\R` matches "new line" for *all* kinds of "new lines", no matter if \r\n Windows, or \n Linux, ... !

And for further reference: study the eclipse regex help pages, for example this [here](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jubula.client.ua.help%2Fhtml%2Freference%2Fnode4.html).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: My objective is to remove the matched lines. Using your suggestion I am now seeing the lines were replaced with blanks. Is it possible to delete the matched lines?

Comment: I have uploaded an image that illustrates what I have.

Comment: I was hopeful after reading this post but as you can see it isn't working well ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27521800/eclipse-how-to-replace-delete-lines-starts-with-particular-word

Comment: The linking was done to show I have been researching and supposedly SO resolved the ques in that linked article. But the image I had attached shows it is not working.

Comment: I have something that appears to work now. To delete the line, you must also remove the line-break, not only the contents of the line. So your Expression should end with \r\n instead of $.

Comment: Use `^\s*tosh4.*$\R?` where `\R` matches any line break style (CRLF, CR or LF).

Comment: Thx. Consider this question answered!

Comment: @ToshBimbra The proper way to indicate an answered question is that you **accept** it, by clicking on the "check mark" icon next to the answer.